# constraints not working properly, Xcode

Tags: xcode, autolayout

what is the reason my constraints are off, i am running it on an iphone7 simulator and I can't get it right. Not sure what other information I can provide, all the details of my constraints are in the images.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a button as the background. (The purple thing) And a plain UILabel as the text.

The good side about this is that it will be very easy to position.

The bad side of this is that having the text color change when on press gets a bit more complicated.

But about your constraints, of the text labels. Check the property inspector and adjust the text alignment so that it's centered.

Answer (score 0):

I highlighted all 4 buttons on the bottom and added constraints to them all at one tim and set equal width and height in add new constraints tab.